# Implicit inheritance working in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Can anyone tell me how the implicit inheritance works in java internally?
What I mean is if I create a class how exactly it extends the Object class in the JVM?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Java forces inheritance on every class. If you do not explicitly inherit from a class, then by default Java assumes that you are inheriting from the class called Object, which does not do much, but does have several useful methods :

1. it implies that every class is descended from Object, since whatever class you inherit from must have inherited from something, which would be either Object or something that inherited from something, etc.
2. the concept of polymorphism implies that you could store any type of object in a variable whose type was Object

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Object class, every class in Java must have a super-class.

There is nothing special about implicit inheritance.  It is simply a syntactic shortcut that means you don't have to write `extends Object`.  At a semantic level, implicit inheritance works exactly the same way as explicit inheritance.

In practice, this means that every class inherits certain standard methods from `Object` ... unless the methods are overridden.  Examples include `equals(Object)`, `hashcode()` and `toString()` which are frequently overridden, and `getClass()` that cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

For all practical reasons, you can think that `class X {` is a syntax sugar for `class X extends Object {`—that's it.