# Implicit constructor call in java

Tags: java, class, constructor, default-constructor

I read this statement in someone's article:

> [An] implicit constructor call occurs when variable of type `B` is defined and instantiated in class `A`, for example, `B b = new B();`.

What does 'implicit constructor' mean? What does it do/how does it relate to local variables? Can you provide an example to help me understand that shows when and why it is advantageous to have an implicit constructor?

Comment: How would you create a `B`, if not by invoking its' constructor?

Comment: If `class B extends A`, then the constructor of `A` will be called when you do `new B()`. Classes always call `super();` as the first thing in their constructor... I think.

Comment: I don't know , I read this in someone article , so I want to understand it by an example .

Comment: @Gendarme , can you give me example  to understand this .

Comment: I have no idea what exactly that article is talking about. It's very vague, and isn't using common terminology.

Comment: `class A { public A() { System.out.print("Hello."); } } class B extends A { } class MyClass { public static void main(String[] args) { new B(); } }` the output of this program will be `"Hello."`.

Comment: hope this link will help you to understand. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019428/implicit-inheritance-working-in-java)

Comment: @RajithPemabandu That doesn't explain the implicit `super()` call.

Comment: @Gendarme I don't see where the article mentions inheritance at all.

Comment: @Gendarme , thank you very much, I understand it but I want to know what is the advantages of this implicit constructor..?

Comment: *"The reason it is required to call a super constructor is that the superclass usually has some state it expects to be in after being constructed, which may include private variables that can't be set in a sub-class. If you don't call the constructor, it would leave the object in a probably invalid state, which can cause all kinds of problems."*

Comment: Ok, thank you all for the help .

Comment: The advantages of an implicit constructor over _what_?  You can write an explicit constructor that does the same thing as the implicit constructor.  The advantage of the implicit constructor here is less meaningless code.

Comment: Implicit constructor call in java .

Comment: What you're showing is an explicit call to the constructor - a `new` expression is always a combination of object allocation and a call to the constructor. If you didn't define a constructor in `B`, the it's an explicit call to an implicitly defined constructor. The source of your quote is using incorrect terminology.

Comment: Not every published article gives correct information. There's a lot of nonsense out there. Do a reality check of claims by comparing them to what the Java Language Specification, the defining document of the Java language, sets forth.

Comment: That's right,  
Not every published article gives correct information,